# graph API search type "page" seems broken?

Tags: rest, facebook-graph-api

I implemented the graph API to search for pages. (`&type=page`)
The API stopped delivering results about 2 days ago without my code being altered. All I get from REST request like that `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={query}&type=page&limit=50&access_token={token}`
is:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Anybody having similar issues?
Thanks in advance for any comments on that.

EDIT:
Okay... This is starting to get mysterious. Using the Facebook API explorer `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/`
I punched in the EXACT same query I am running from any other client (my own browser, the server which sends the requests normally, a REST client app for firefox) and again: All came back blank, EXCEPT the one from the official explorer, which delivers top notch results.
So it is probably not the access-token, probably not the query itself (for it is tested working).
Hmm... Is it time to file a bug report? What other methods of decrypting what's going on comes to your minds?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the graph api in similar ways earlier using a script I've made. The scripts purpose was to try to find fanpages for a given company. I wanted to narrow down the number of results so the query included the city which the company was located. This script worked fine just before christmast atleast. Today I fired it up again, something had changed. First the search required an access_token, second it returned an empty resultset. I can no longer include the company city in the query, as this turns out to not find anything. If I search for the company name I get results, but far to many of them.

Comment: I implemented the access-token already (it was required when I first built the app). In my case the response does not change, regardless of what I put in the query parameter. Plus: Providing the city in the query parameter when using the app explorer gives beautiful results. Seems like I have to stay up late today ;)